# What is meant with "reconciliation" in CV QKD?

Tags: information-theory, continuous-variable, key-distribution

I am working on a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08500v2) about Continuous Variable QKD. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08500v2)

I read about direct and reverse reconciliation in this paper. I don't understand what exactly *Reconciliation* is? Reconciliation algorithms, reconciliation protocols and so on.

I am really confused. Can any one explain reconciliation to me?

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper where you encountered this so that we can better help you.

Comment: I believe the term "reconciliation" or "information reconciliation" refers to the error correction step that comes after Alice and Bob have generated their raw key. Their raw keys $K_A$ and $K_B$ will not be exactly equal so Alice and Bob have to communicate some classical information to allow them to error correct $K_A$ and $K_B$ so that after the procedure they have new keys $J_A$, $J_B$ such that $J_A = J_B$ (with high probability).

Comment: @Rammus Exactly what I thought, I was writing up an answer:)

Comment: @JSdJ thanks for your comment. I added the paper link.

Comment: @Rammus as I understand, reverse reconciliation and post selection are two different method to reach significant transmission distances. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the paper you are reading is referring to [information reconciliation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution#Information_reconciliation_and_privacy_amplification)

Information reconciliation is a vital part of post-processing in QKD, to limit (or erase in the best-case scenario) the amount of errors/differences between the key of Alice and Bob.

In that sense, it is a form of (**classical**) error-correction, and, broadly speaking, it works like this:

- Alice and Bob run a QKD protocol together and both obtain a *raw key* $k_{a}$ and $k_{b}$ of whatever length.
- In real world scenarios, $k_{a} \not = k_{b}$ due to measurement errors, imperfect channels etc. Alice and Bob want the *exact* same key, so they need to fix this.
- However, $k_{a} \simeq k_{b}$; we can write $k_{b} = k_{a} + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the error/difference between Alice and Bob, and therefore $\epsilon \simeq \overrightarrow{0}$ (i.e. $\epsilon$ is a bitstring with almost all entries equal to $0$ because there are not that many errors).
- Alice and Bob have (in advance) agreed to use a certain *error code* to perform error correction. This error code is some linear function $f$ that calculates the *syndrome* $s$ of a key. Note that the error code may or may not be secret to Alice and Bob.
- It is **hard** to reverse this function in general. $s$ is of considerably shorter length than $k$. So, there are multiple $k$ with the same $s$.
- Alice calculates $s_{a} = f(k_{a})$ and publicly communicates $s_{a}$. Any Eve cannot do anything with this because the function is in general hard to reverse.
- Bob receives $s_{a}$ and calculates $s_{b}$. The function is linear, so $s_{b} = f(k_{b}) = f(k_{a} + \epsilon) = f(k_{a}) + f(\epsilon) = s_{a} + s_{\epsilon}$. Therefore, the 'error syndrome' $s_{\epsilon} = s_{a} - s_{b}$ encodes only information about $\epsilon$.
- Only Bob can calculate $s_{\epsilon}$. Because the code was designed properly (and for this exact function), and because $\epsilon \simeq \overrightarrow{0}$, Bob can *decode* the error syndrome to estimate $\epsilon$: $\hat{\epsilon} = f^{-1}(s_{\epsilon})$.
- Finally, Bob calculates $\hat{k_{a}} = k_{b} - \hat{\epsilon}$. If the code is any good,
  $\hat{k_{a}} - k_{a} \rightarrow 0$, i.e. Alices key and Bobs corrected key are very close/almost always the same.

There are **a lot** of important details I have grossed over, but this is the general idea. For a nice introduction of information reconciliation/error correction in the scope of QKD, check [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1616).

Note that the above is error-correction for *general* QKD, not necessarily only for continuous variable QKD. I suspect that there are small discrepancies between the two, but the main goal should be the same.